# Typescript Node.js project - deployment to production workflow

Tags: node.js, typescript, github, production

How should I setup my dist build and production deployment workflow for my Node.js server app? (NestJS API)?

My current workflow:

1. Commit changes to `production` branch
2. Production server with `pm2` automatically pull changes from this repo
3. Automatic `npm install` on prod server.
4. Automatic `npm run build` on prod server.
5. Automatic `pm2 start` on prod server.

The main problem I see in this workflow is that I am running build on production server. This means that I need all devDependencies on server and also I am doing performance spikes on server when building.

I already configured GitHub Actions on my repo to build my code and save it as artifact on commit, but now I am stuck.

- Should I commit built source code to repo and then use `pm2` hook on production?
- Should I download artifact by some script to production, unpack it and run it? I see few problems here:

  - `/dist` folder (artifact) does not have package.json and assets
  - I lost Git functionality, so I need to always delete old source and unpack new source

Answer (score 0):

I don't have all the info I need, but I guess you should run the build step on a CI/CD tool (TravisCI for example), and push the content of the `/dist` folder to your production server afterwards. Then, pm2 would only run this production build.

Comment: This is exactly how I am planning this, but then I must commit built code to git, so pm2 will be able to pull it right?

Comment: There are many ways to do. You can decide to commit built code to git (in a separate orphan branch for example), or you can upload it the the server using ssh/scp directly from your CI/CD Pipeline !

What I would do is a shell script that can be called either by you or by the CI/CD, which deploys the /dist content to the production server

Comment: Another solution would be using Github Packages, which acts like a private npm repository. You could deploy your app as a package and ask your production server to install it